# Stuck at blank purple screen after login Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: login, gdm

After logging in after a reboot, it just removes the login window thing and gives a blank purple screen with a mouse cursor instead of my desktop. I can ctrl-alt-f2 and then ctrl-alt-f1 back and it'll reload the greeter and let me log in after that, but it's really annoying and I'd rather avoid having to do that. I'm running 20.04.3 on a Thinkpad P51s. Installing all the updates and messing w graphics drivers hasn't done anything. Help please!

Comment: I think you should post your hardware, kernel version and if you have installed all updates.

Comment: I had a similar issue and for some reason it was caused by having too many monitors plugged in, I unplugged one of them and it fixed the problem. Might not be relevant to your situation, just commenting in case it helps someone in the future.